# Decimal scale in Redshift after division by literal

Tags: floating-point, amazon-redshift

Trying to understand this behavior

```
 CREATE TABLE tab (x DECIMAL(10,0), y DECIMAL(10,0))
 INSERT INTO tab VALUES(1, 3)
```

`select x / y from tab` will return 0.3333.... to 11 decimal places according to [the rules in Redshift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_numeric_computations201.html).

What I don't understand is: if I divide by a literal casted to the same type (`x / 3::decimal(10,0)`), I get exactly 4 decimal places (`0.3333`)

How can I get more fine-grained control over the precision/scale of the result, besides writing the quotient to a table first or worse, using `float`?

Comment: From the above Amazon doc: "You might also encounter cases where the scale of computed values varies or is unexpected." - FWIW it looks like Redshift is ignoring the cast to decimal for the literal and using the actual precision (1) instead of the cast precision (10), which would result in a scale of 4 according to the defined rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using your example tab table

```
select x / y,
       ((x/ 3::decimal)),
       ((x/ (select 3)::decimal)),
       ((x/ (select 3)::decimal))::decimal(10,6)
       from tab;
```

returns

> 0.33333333333 0.3333  0.3333333333333333333   0.333333

You see in the 3rd example, replacing your 3::decimal with (select 3)::decimal increased the precision a lot.

If you need to set a output precision, you can do this like in my 4th example `((x/ (select 3)::decimal))::decimal(10,6)`

Comment: Weird that (select 3)::decimal behaves differently than 3::decimal